# copying data from pointer-to-array to pointer-to-array

Tags: pointer-to-array

How would I go about copying the content of a pointer to an array to a temporary pointer to an array, and then making the original pointer point to the same thing the temporary pointer is pointing too? In code form, :

```
bankAccount **array = new bankAccount* [maxSize];
bankAccount **temp = new bankAccount* [maxSize + 5];

for(int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++)
{
    temp[i] = &array[i]
}

delete [] array;
array = temp;
```

When I compile the code above, I get the error:

> assigning to bankAccount * from incompatible type
>    bankAccount **; remove

Comment: Remove the ampersand &

Comment: @Pepe I revised my code, and you are correct.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: There is no "pointer to array" here. You have an array of pointers.